# Akward sounding paragraph

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence

> The valves, **by way of the flaps** are able to control the flow of blood through the heart because the flaps open and close during the contractions of the heart.

I think the bolded part especially, but also the sentence as a whole   sounds a little bit awkward. Is their a way to make it more  coherent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the sentence as follows:

> "By opening and closing the flaps with each contraction, the valves control the amount of blood flowing through the heart."

This construction is still a bit awkward because of the lack of definition. Flaps and valves both need descriptors unless they are earlier defined.

Here is an alternate:

> The opening and closing of flaps allows the valves to control the heart's blood flow.

Answer (score 0):

Blood flow in the heart is controlled by flaps within its valves, which in turn are opened and closed by the heart's contractions.

Answer (score 0):

Written as it is, I would place a comma after flaps.

The valves, by way of the flaps, are able to control the flow of blood through the heart because the flaps open and close during the contractions of the heart.